# How to replace all domain names from a string for a `✦` character?

Tags: php

The most I've gotten:

```
$name = str_replace("*.*", "✦", $name);
```

And for example:

```
$name = "Hello | google.com"
```

would be replaced to:

```
$name = "Hello | ✦"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What research have you done? Where *specifically* are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `regex`

```
<?php 
preg_replace('/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i','✦',$name);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace()` for pattern matching replacement.

```
$name = "Hello | google.com";
//$name = preg_replace("/[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+/", "✦", $name);
 $name = preg_replace("/((http|https)\:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\?\:@\-_=#]+\.([a-zA-Z0-9\&\.\/\?\:@\-_=#])+/", "✦", $name);

echo $name;
```

Comment: works perfect, but is it possible to exclude my own domain from this somehow?